# Javascript different tab blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am developing a block multiple tabs on a website to display some categories with X number of posts on each tab.

I don't know much about javascript, and I found this to make the effects on the tabs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.maintab").click(function () { // When a link is clicked
        $(".tabactive").removeClass("tabactive"); // switch all tabs off
        $(this).addClass("tabactive"); // switch this tab on
        $(".maintabcontent").slideUp(); // slide all content up
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title"); // slide this content up
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is, when I have two blocks, each one with different tabs, if I chose a tab on the second block, the 1st one closes(slides up), and vice versa.

I want them to always be open, no mater what tab i chose of the blocks. Can you help me with the javascript for this? BTW the slide effects are not important, you could put toggle() on it.

EDIT: http://paste2.org/Y3J1Lm7d

Here it is a Sample of one block

Comment: you need to share the html sample also

Comment: I don't understand, if you want both to always be open, what's the point of having tabs...?

Comment: @Crazysheep the idea is, having a category, and each tab arrange it differently. For example, views, most popular(based on rating), date...

Comment: @ArunPJohny http://paste2.org/Y3J1Lm7d sorry, here you go. My second block just changes the number on the id for "maintab"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>So from what I can gather you just want to use the tabs as 'buttons' without actually affecting the 'blocks' of content underneath?</s>

In that case simply remove the lines that handle the sliding up and down of content.

This javascript should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.maintab").click(function () { // When a link is clicked
        $(".tabactive").removeClass("tabactive"); // switch all tabs off
        $(this).addClass("tabactive"); // switch this tab on

        var content_show = $(this).attr("title"); // id of the linked content
        $("#"+content_show).siblings().slideUp(); // slide siblings up
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown(); // slide itself down
    });
  });
</script>
```

If these are the two blocks of your tab content:

```
<div id="TabElements1">
    <div id="maintab1" class="maintabcontent">
        {custom category="2" aviable="main" from="0" limit="16" order="rating" cache="no"}
    </div>
    <div id="maintab2" class="maintabcontent">
        {custom category="3" aviable="main" from="0" limit="16" cache="no"}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="TabElements2">
    <div id="maintab3" class="maintabcontent">
        {custom category="2" aviable="main" from="0" limit="16" order="rating" cache="no"}
    </div>
    <div id="maintab4" class="maintabcontent">
        {custom category="3" aviable="main" from="0" limit="16" cache="no"}
    </div>
</div>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cz5te/2/

Comment: No, that doesn't work. That changes the buttons, but it doesn't display the content itself. So i need something that "pulls" the correspondent content :/

The problem with the script i have, is that when i click on a button of the 2nd block, it will slide up the 1st one. I don't want it to do nothing.

Comment: @PedroLino I'm sorry I'm still very confused then. If neither of the blocks ever slide up, how can they ever slide down?

Comment: The slideup, hides the content right? So i have block A with the tabs 1, 2 and block B with tabs 3, 4. Tabs 1 and 3 are active when i load the page. Now if i click tab 4, all the content slides up, and only 4 shows up. What i want, is that when i click one tab on B, it doesn't slide up tabs on A.

Comment: @PedroLino By 'pull' the content do you mean pull down or pull from a server? http://jsfiddle.net/Cz5te/1/ is this the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: With pull i mean showing the content on that tab. No, you only have one block there. Basicly you would need to duplicate the HTML info, to make another "block" of tabs.

Comment: let me give you an example of what i basicly have. http://docs.dlestarter.com/episode/ so you can see there that 4 "lines" (what i call blocks) with multiple episodes. If you click on one a tab, the other lines close. What i want is them to stay "open". Just that.

Comment: @PedroLino see my latest edit. I think it should be what you're after. Next time it would be helpful to include all relevant html - having the html for both blocks would've made it easier to undersand.